# Using Current Date Time in SAS

Tags: date, sas, where-clause

I am selecting the data from a table using a date string. I would like to select all rows that have a update time stamp greater than or equal to today.

The simplest way that I can think of is to put today's date in the string, and it works fine.

WHERE UPDATE_DTM >'29NOV2016:12:00'DT;

However, if I want to put something like today's date or system date, what should I put?
I used today(), but it returned all rows in the table. I am not sure if it's because today() in SAS refers to the date 1/1/1960? I also tried &sysdate, but it returned an error message seems like it requires a date conversion.

WHERE UPDATE_DTM > TODAY();

Any ideas? Your thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: `today()` does not refer to 1/1/1960, unless you run it on a machine that is set to 1/1/1960...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATETIME()` is the datetime equivalent of `TODAY()` (but includes the current time).  You could also use `dhms(TODAY(),0,0,0)` if you want effectively midnight (or, for your example above, `dhms(TODAY(),12,0,0)` to get noon today).

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot. I was thinking to set another variable BEG_DATE=TODAY(), and then convert the date format. The one that you provided is much easier and works great!